# Filter Critcal and Error events to my CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell, events, system

I am currently writing a script that gives me the Application and system Log files from event viewer from any workstation that I request.

I would like to filter my CSV file so that when I open it, the critical Errors would be Orange and Errors would be Red.

Is there a way to do this? This here is my current script

```
$Search = read-host "Enter Workstation ID" 
(Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) | Out-File C:\temp\test.csv
(Get-EventLog -LogName System -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) | Out-File C:\temp\test.csv
cmd /c pause
```

Comment: Tagging a language would probably be a good idea. I'm guessing `powershell`?

Comment: Yes sorry this is powershell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV file est basicaly a plain-text file. You can't output colors to a plain-text file.

Comment: You can, assuming it is installed, create an Excel file using its Excel.Application com object and do all the formatting you'd like to it once you get the data in there. If you look through my answer history I've got some Excel answers that do some neat things with data manipulation and formatting.

Comment: I agree with you. the question is about CSV files and not Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider checking out the Export-Csv cmdlet

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx

Using `"| Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv"` vs `"| Out-File C:\temp\test.csv"` will allow you to filter your output in Excel vs having each attribute listed in one column in Excel. The filtering might be as valuable as whatever you were trying to achieve with the colour coding :)